# Homotopic equivalence embedding and contractible quotient space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Let $(X,A)$ be a $CW$ pair(assume X is connected) such that the embedding $i: A \hookrightarrow X$ is a homotopic equivalence, do we always have the quotient space $X/A$ is contractible? (Hatcher uses something like this in his book, but I don't know if this general proposition holds)

Moreover, if this is true, is the condition that $(X,A)$ is a CW pair necessary here? Can we simply assume $(X,A)$ is a pair of space and its subspace?

Comment: Which bit of the book are you referring to?

Comment: @KennyWong For example, Ex. 4.2.18 from here https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf#page=399#  And I think something similar has appeared somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just quoting from Hatcher here: If $(X,A)$ is a CW pair, then $(X,A)$ has the homotopy extension property (0.16). Hence, if the inclusion $i : A \to X$ is a homotopy equivalence, then $A$ is a deformation retract of $X$ (0.20).

But once you know that $A$ is a deformation retract of $X$, the result is easy. Let $p: X \to A$ be the retraction, obeying the condition that $p|_A = {\rm id}_A$, and let $F:X\times[0,1]\to X$ be the homotopy between $i \circ p $ and ${\rm id}_X$ obeying $F|_{A \times [0,1]} = {\rm id}_{A\times [0,1]}$. Then $i$ and $p$ descend to well-defined continuous maps $\tilde i: A/A \to X/A$ and $\tilde p : X/A \to A/A$, and the homotopy $F$ descends to a homotopy $\tilde F$ between $\tilde i \circ \tilde p$ and ${\rm id}_{X/A}$. So $X/A$ and $A/A$ are homotopy equivalent. But $A/A$ is a point, so $X/A$ is contractible.

Comment: Is $F(a,t)\in A, \forall a\in A$?(The definition of deformation retract doesn't seem require this. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retract). If not, then $F$ doesn't descend very well to $\tilde F: X/A \times I  \to X/A$

Comment: That's right. This condition is absolutely essential. See page 2 of Hatcher.

Comment: Okay~~~~Hatcher's deformation retract is the STRONG deformation retract in wikipedia~~~

Comment: Oh my word. That is so confusing!

Comment: Thank you and +1! Let me think for a while before taking you answer.